# Firebase Performance - Added the SDK to app, but console still says to add SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/troubleshooting?authuser=0&platform=android#sdk-not-detected

I tried all of these steps but It doesn't seem activated.

Project level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1' 
}
```

app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'
```

What is the problem?

I saw 2 lines in log:

```
2020-02-19 23:13:41.574 20828-21030/com.sample.project I/FirebasePerformance: HTTP Method is null or invalid: <com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzcv$zzb@1144676 number=0 name=HTTP_METHOD_UNKNOWN>
2020-02-19 23:13:41.574 20828-21030/com.sample.project W/FirebasePerformance: Unable to process the PerfMetric due to missing or invalid values. See earlier log statements for additional information on the specific missing/invalid values.
```

And there is full log:

```
2020-02-19 23:13:22.514 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzav' is: '0.01'.
2020-02-19 23:13:22.515 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: e12e7132a8e743108f1f08efbb560633
2020-02-19 23:13:23.718 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.718 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.719 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.852 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.864 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.864 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.867 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:23.880 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving rate limiting time range (in seconds) configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.884 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzan' is: '600'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.884 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving trace event count foreground configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.886 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzax' is: '300'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.887 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving rate limiting time range (in seconds) configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.889 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzan' is: '600'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.889 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving trace event count background configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.892 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzau' is: '30'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.892 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving rate limiting time range (in seconds) configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.895 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzan' is: '600'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.895 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network event count foreground configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.899 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzal' is: '700'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.899 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving rate limiting time range (in seconds) configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.903 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzan' is: '600'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.903 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network event count background configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.907 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzai' is: '70'.
2020-02-19 23:13:23.917 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaj' is: 'FIREPERF'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.408 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.409 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.412 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.412 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.415 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.416 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:24.419 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/212110482849328/mobile_sdk_gk 919b 555ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:24.425 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.428 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.428 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.432 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:24.439 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.443 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.717 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: onResume(): com.avea.oim.SplashActivity: 2261790 microseconds
2020-02-19 23:13:24.721 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.721 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.723 20828-20828/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.725 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.725 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.728 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:24.730 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _as 2261ms
2020-02-19 23:13:24.732 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.735 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.736 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.739 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:24.742 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving trace sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:24.747 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaw' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.573 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.574 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.575 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.575 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.577 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.578 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:25.583 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.058 20828-20979/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.058 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.061 20828-20979/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.061 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.061 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.064 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.065 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/212110482849328/activities 15b 360ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:26.066 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.068 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.068 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.071 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.075 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.079 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.322 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.324 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.325 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.326 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.326 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.328 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.331 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://sample.project.com.tr/pars/rest/nop 0b 737ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:26.331 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.335 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.335 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.338 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.342 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.348 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.395 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.395 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.396 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.396 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.399 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.399 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.402 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.584 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.585 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.588 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.588 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.588 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.592 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.594 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://sample.project.com.tr/messages 0b 180ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:26.595 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.599 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.599 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.603 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:26.606 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:26.610 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.489 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.489 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.490 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.490 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.497 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.497 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.500 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:35.600 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.601 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.602 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.602 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.602 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.604 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:35.605 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://sample.project.com/users 0b 98ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:35.606 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.608 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.608 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.610 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:35.612 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:35.614 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.167 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.168 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.169 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.169 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.172 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.172 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.188 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:40.759 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.759 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.761 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.761 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.761 20828-21045/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.763 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:40.764 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://sample.project.com.tr/rest/v2 0b 569ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:40.765 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.766 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.766 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.768 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:40.770 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving network request sampling rate configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:40.775 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzak' is: '1.0'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.437 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzah' is: 'false'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.437 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.439 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzag' is: 'null'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.439 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.445 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.447 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.449 20828-20974/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:41.558 20828-20976/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Max Duration (in minutes) of single Session configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.558 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.560 20828-20976/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzaq' is: '240'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.560 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.561 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.563 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:41.565 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://sample.project.com.tr/rest/try 0b 71ms,
2020-02-19 23:13:41.566 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving master flag for Firebase Performance SDK enabled configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.568 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzap' is: 'true'.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.568 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Retrieving Firebase Performance SDK disabled versions configuration value.
2020-02-19 23:13:41.571 20828-21030/com.sample.project D/FirebasePerformance: Config resolver result for flag: 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzam' is: ''. Resolving value as 'false'
2020-02-19 23:13:41.574 20828-21030/com.sample.project I/FirebasePerformance: HTTP Method is null or invalid: <com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzcv$zzb@1144676 number=0 name=HTTP_METHOD_UNKNOWN>
2020-02-19 23:13:41.574 20828-21030/com.sample.project W/FirebasePerformance: Unable to process the PerfMetric due to missing or invalid values. See earlier log statements for additional information on the specific missing/invalid values.
```

Comment: Any luck with this Volkan?

Comment: Any update on this issue ?. For me also same behaviour

Comment: A sdk in the project has been saved as the default sdk. This prevents the actual project from appearing.

Comment: I found my ad blocker was preventing performance from posting data to Firebase, after disabling it for few minutes Firebase was able to detect my sdk setup!

Answer (score 6):

I'm also facing same issue. After I added the below lines it worked for me.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
```

Above line inside application tag in the manifest.xml

**In Code :**

```
FirebasePerformance.getInstance().isPerformanceCollectionEnabled = true
    trace = FirebasePerformance.getInstance().newTrace(STARTUP_TRACE_NAME)
    Log.d("TAG", "Starting trace")
    trace.start()
    trace.putAttribute("experiment", "A");
    trace.incrementMetric(REQUESTS_COUNTER_NAME, 1)
    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
        trace.stop()
        Log.d("TAG", "Stop trace")
    },3000)
```

**In Log :**

2020-03-06 14:42:34.773 10486-10540/com.android.appperformancetracker D/FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _as 624ms
2020-03-06 14:42:36.606 10486-10540/com.android.appperformancetracker D/FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - startup_trace 3002ms

**In Firebase Dashboad:**

[image]

Comment: Live apps should not set firebase_performance_logcat_enabled as true, so this can be added only in debug manifest.